# calling Django API using apache (mod_wsgi)

Tags: java, python, django, celery

I have a frontend web tool which interacts with REST API written in danjgo. Each API calls take long time to process the call and is also CPU/GPU intensive. So I am planning to run only 1 call at a time and putting rest of the calls in queue. Now I am not sure if Celery with redis can be helpful here or should I stick with job queue approach at the java side.

So, the tool would be used by multiple users and and so each user would have their jobs. So, I need to put the jobs in queue so that they can be processed one by one asynchronously. Would Celery be helpful here?

Comment: Definitely. Your Celery cluster can contain powerful machines that your distributed tasks would benefit from. Django would just offload that computation to Celery, and wait for results...

Comment: so you mean, django or Celery would maintain a queue system and they would process them one by one. As job gets finished, it would keep sending the message back to Django and django would communicate with apache.?

Comment: Yes. Django is the `producer`. Celery is the `consumer` from the `queue`(s) managed by Redis.